# Avoid problems in key-controlled HTML forms if key is permanently pressed

Tags: html, forms

I created a simple web application with two pages. For a better usability I make it key-controlled, which leads to a problem. This is the workflow:

1. A form in which pressing *ENTER* key (or a button) executes the *submit*. This starts a database query.
2. The second page then displays the query result; a "*Back to start*" button calls the form again. The form is refilled with the same values again. The button can also be activated by *ENTER*.

The problem occurs when a user permanently press the *ENTER* key. Then dozens of querys are executed and this nearly kills the application.

Any ideas how to handle this without losing comfort? Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using any server-side language like PHP or similar, you should add a flag to the user session which indicates whether the form has been submitted previously. You can also count the number of submits if you want the form to be submitted multiple times but not infinite.

If that doesn't fit your needs, please describe your execution environment more precisely.